# Find-Class Java

Tags: java, file, javafx

I am working on a project where I have to work with some .txt files. At first I put all my files in the Project-Folder (I know that it is not ideal). Since I want to get everything structured, I created packages and put my files in there (I know that I have to change the paths in my code). However, now the code where it first loads a .txt file look like this:

```java
public ArrayList<Schnipsel> createList(ArrayList<Schnipsel> pwl, String lvlDateiTxT) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file:Application/Assets/Levels/file.txt"));
    String passwordString = "";
    int passwordDifficulty;
    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        passwordString = input.next();
        passwordDifficulty = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(passwordString + " " + passwordDifficulty);
                pwl.add(new Schnipsel(passwordString, passwordDifficulty));
    }
    return pwl;
}
```

When the scanner is called I hand over the parameter where the File is.

[Here you can see my current project-structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9bcA.png)

Before I redesigned my project structure everything worked fine, but now it won't find the .txt files. (on the other hand I dont have the same issue with the sound files nor the graphic files, which I obviously dont load with the File-Class).

It would be awesome if someone knows what to do. I really tried a lot.
(e.g.:"file:Application/Assets/Levels/file.txt", "Application/Assets/Levels/file.txt", "../Application/Assets/Levels/file.txt", `getClass().getResource("path").toString()`

and so on...)

Also, since I have to export the project as JAR, I cant put the absolut path there (which was the only way i worked btw)

Comment: you'll want to put those files in your resources folder.  You can then use getResourceAsStream: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-  Ex: InputStream inStream = ThisFilesClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/your/package/name/Resources/" + dirname + "/" + filename);

Comment: Unrelated: *"I have to export the project as JAR,"* -> it may be easier to use Maven and the [`maven-javafx-plugin`](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxjlink-options) to package your application using jlink as a zip file, rather than trying to a jar from it, which can be tricky for JavaFX applications as the JavaFX libraries are modular and you can't include multiple modules in a single jar file.  Another advantage of using Maven is that it provides a standard directory structure and packaging for resources, which may incidentally help solve your resource issue.

Comment: Instructions on using Maven with JavaFX (if you want to do that) are at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Answer (score 0):

You can place the files in src/main/resources and load them from the resources. A quick guide to this - https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Answer (score 0):

With your current approach, your current working directory of the jvm is probably different than the one you expect it to be, resulting in the file path not existing relative to it. Using `getClass().getResource()` gives you an URL to the resource from the same class loader (practically the same .jar for most cases) as the class you're calling the method on, sharing the package name (eg. the resource "abc.txt", when loaded from "a.b.c.D" will look for "a/b/c/abc.txt").
To circumvent that issue with the package name being prepended, I usually use the class loader's getResource method, which doesn't modify the path in any way: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("abc.txt")`. You can also directly get the resource as an InputStream: `.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt")`.

Both of those methods will return null if the resource wasn't found. As for how to include the resource: That depends on your build system, but more often than not, the `src/main/resources` folder will be responsible for it.

Comment: With my given folder structure and this line:
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("hardPw.txt").toString()));
I get:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null